# How to use adjustbox with longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, adjustbox

I really like to use `adjustbox` package with my numerical data which often is too wide and when `\tiny` font is still too large. However, the problem is when my table is too high. Can I somehow use both `adjustbox` and `longtable`? This is my current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{table} 
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[tbph]{cccccc}   
  &     Homer J. Simpson &     Marge Simpson &     Bart Simpson &     Lisa Simpson &     Maggie Simpson  \\ 
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\      
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\ 
       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\ 
       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\          
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\       
       Age &     38 &     34 &     10 &     8  &     1 \\             
       
       
\end{tabular} 
\end{adjustbox} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The short answer is no.  Longtable interacts directly with \output and cannot be inside anything else.

Comment: scaling tables never gives a usable result, so the fact that it doesn't work with longtable isn't an issue.  Use `\footnotesize` or, if you must, `\tiny`.  if that is too large re-arrange the data so that it fits on the page.

Comment: `tabular` does not have a `[tbph]` argument, as you show in the question, did you mean to put that on the `table` environment?

Answer (score 2):

- what is your problem? That table is to wide to be fin on page? Use of `adjustbox` for this is not a solution ...
- you should use a `longrable` that table can be broken between pages
- `longtable` had not be enclosed in `table` float nor in any kind of box
- you should find a way to make your columns headers shorter or written in two lines, tat table be narrower from `\textwidth`, for examples as:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage{longtable, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[htbp]{cccccc}
    \hline
    & \makecell{Homer J.\\ Simpson} 
            & \makecell{Marge\\ Simpson}
                    & \makecell{Bart\\ Simpson} 
                            & \makecell{Lisa\\ Simpson}
                                    & \makecell{Maggie\\ Simpson}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{Continued on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\

Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
Age &   38  &   34  &   10  &   8   &   1                           \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout) Is this what you looking for?

**Edit:**
To table are added are column heads on each page and table foot (Continue on the next page).